# Tableview stutter after upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

After I switched my project from: 
`xcode 6.4, ios 8 target, swift 1.2` ->
`xcode 7, ios 9 target, swift 2` 
all of my table views suddenly started to stutter. To verify my code, I created a new project in xcode 7, target ios 9 and copied the code there, no stutter. 
So my guess is that some of the endless `build settings` get set different when creating the newer project?

Comment: Are you sure that the changes you made to switch from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0 haven't changed the performance of you table Views?

Comment: @Abizern I'm using a really simple debug code, 1 section, 100 rows hardcoded, the cell only have one subview of type [TagListView](https://github.com/xhacker/TagListView) to which I add 4 tags in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It runs flawlessly in a brand new project, but as soon as I move the code to my old project, stutter is introduced.